# href is not working

Tags: php, html

I have a prolem when I want to load bootstrap. This is my bootstrap.min.css directory:

> C:/xampp/htdocs/OOPPhp/perpustakaan/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

Then, I want to load it with this code:

```
<link href="<?= str_replace('\\', '/', baseDir); ?> /bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

I have define baseDir before to get perpustakaan directory using this:

```
define('baseDir', dirname(__DIR__));
```

But link tag not working. I try to echo the link in href and the directory result is true. Why? This is my directory:

> ```
> /perpustakaan
>     /bootstrap
>        /css
>           /bootstrap.min.css
>        /js
>        /images
>     /ui
>        /header.php
>        /listCD.php
>     /index.php
> ```

The code is in header.php and I use include_once for header.php in listCD.php and index.php

Comment: replace <?= with <?php

Comment: Do you really need to use the directory function for this? Can't you use relative path to solve this problem?

Comment: I have try to replace it, but still not working

Comment: If you are using chrome browser pease inspect element or view page source for the url is the same as you want?

Comment: please tell your root directory.

Comment: I need it because I use include_once for page with this code in many php files and the php files are in different directory

Comment: try @Naga's answer

Comment: Doesn't matter. Relative path can be used to access the root url & will follow the path from there. Check my answer.

Comment: I have update my question. Thank you.

Comment: @RiefSapthana - my recommendation will help you do that. just use the ./ version and you will be able to access the folder. Make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: I have tried it and it's just working in index.php

Comment: Try adding this -> "../../" - figure out the relative path as its easier for you to deploy without tinkering with the basedir.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<link href="<?='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/OOPPhp/perpustakaan';?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using relative path to solve the problem rather than using the basedir?

Using "../" to navigate 1 directory above.

```
 <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Using "./" to access root directory.

```
<link href="./css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```